# How to append new line \n in a loop

Tags: bash, loops, newline

I want to add a new line character '\n' at the end of each line in my file.

Here is my code:

```
while read -r line
do
echo "$line"|awk -F'\t' '{
        print($1);
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++){
                split($i,arr,":")
                print(arr[1])
        };
}' | tr '\n' '\t' | tr '|' ' ' | tr '/' ' ' | {END OF LINE, WANNA ADD NEW LINE} 
>> genotype_processed.txt

done < file_in
```

Also, is there any way that I can combine the 3 tr commands into one? They just look too redundant.

Many thanks!

**EDIT**:

The input looks like this:

```
id123    0|1:a:b:c    0/0:i:j:k    ...
id456    1/1:j:f:z    1|0:.:j:v    ...
...
```

The desired output:

```
id123    0 1    0 0    ...
id456    1 1    1 0    ...
...
```

Comment: A simple `echo` doesn't work?

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio No, which is really weird. I tried | echo '\n', which is not working obviously. Then | echo "\n", ended up only \n in my file. And then printf and print are also not working. I don't know what to do now :(

Comment: Because `echo` only prints it's args, not input. Instead of using `echo` after the pipe, you can also insert a newline with `| sed 's/$/\n/'` which replaces the end of the current line with `\n`

Comment: @Zelnes The sed after the pipe works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: Why are you not doing all this looping inside one `awk` instead of spawning 4+ processes on every line? You're calling `awk` anyway, drop the `read` and let it process the whole file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could open the output file only once, at the end of the `while` loop, and then do whatever you want to output within the loop.

```sh
while read -r line
do
    echo "$line"|awk -F'\t' '{
        print($1);
        for (i=2; i<=NF; i++){
                split($i,arr,":")
                print(arr[1])
        };
    }' | tr '\n' '\t' | tr '|' ' ' | tr '/' ' '
    # This will be the new "newline"
    echo
done < file_in >genotype_processed.txt
```

And by the way, your loop could be improved, I think, by using a single command to do the replacements. Probably a `sed` could be a good choice.
Provide us more example of input and expected output

### EDIT

After your input/output description, I think you could improve this part a lot.

You do `while read line; do echo "$line" | awk '...'; done <input` which is basically what you would get by doint a single `awk '...' input`.

I don't get exactly what you want to achieve, I think you misunderstand some things, but if what I think is right, then this is what you want.

```sh
sed -r 's/:[^[:blank:]]+//g; s/[|/]/ /g' input
```

Here, I first remove what follows the first `:` for in each column, and then I replace the characters `|` or `/` with a space.
Does that meets your needs ?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
while read -r line
 do
newline="\n"
echo $line$newline >> genotype_processed.txt
done < file_in
```

Or use `"$line"$newline` if needing to retain original formatting of `$line` according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're overcomplicating this. ([XY Problem?](http://xyproblem.info/))

```
$: sed 's,[|/], ,g; s/:[^   ]*//g;' file_in > genotype_processed.txt
```

I sub'd all `|` and `/` with spaces, and any `:` followed by any number of non-tabs with nothing.

I used a single truncating output redirection since I did it all in one step. If there was stuff in the file you wanted to keep, then go back to the append.